# Facebook API mark a thread as "read"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to find a way to POST changes to one of the Threads object fields in my inbox to mark it as **"read"**, i.e. change *unread* from **1** to **0** as seen below from the JSON response I get:

```
"unread": 1, 
  "id": "1643543545", 
  "updated_time": "2013-02-12T14:53:26+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      { 
       .
       .
       .
       } 
   ] 
  }
```

However, I am a bit lost in finding out which part of the API document talks about that and which objects into which you can POST and alter their fields. Looking at the Thread object, what's mentioned there is only the ability to fetch data in read-only manner. There's no mention whatsoever if the object's fields can be updated or altered, i.e. change unread from **1** to **0**.

Is it possible in the first place, or POST is only dedicated to specific part of the API lie "feeds", "messages", etc.

If such think do not exist, any ideas on how to do that would be appreciated ( you'll get a discontinued Canadian penny as a token of appreciation :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API, mark inbox as read?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7609620/facebook-graph-api-mark-inbox-as-read)

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible for developers to mark as thread or message as "read".

Possible duplicate of:
[Facebook Graph API, mark inbox as read?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7609620/facebook-graph-api-mark-inbox-as-read)

Comment: I am aware it's a duplicate, had to resurrect it from the ashes!

Comment: No problem, it is still not posible. Please mark as completed if this answered your question.